# HVAC Gas furnace with added heat pump. Thermostat loses power while heating with gas

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat, gas, heat-pump

I have a medium efficiency gas furnace with an add-on Trane air to air heat pump.  The heat pump kit is TAYPLUS103A.  I noticed that in cold weather when the gas furnace runs, the gas ignites, and after warming up the fan comes on.  Then the gas and fan run together for about 2 minutes.  Then the gas flame stops, and at the same time the thermostat loses power and stays off for about 2 minutes while the fan continues to run to extract the heat from the plenum.  I have checked the limit switch and it is staying closed so the furnace is not overheating. Because the gas only runs for a few minutes and then the thermostat has to reset every time it loses power, it is hard for the furnace to warm up the house when it is really cold outside. Why does the thermostat lose power?

Comment: Providing make/model for both the furnace and the thermostat would be most helpful. Additionally, can you please define what you mean when you say the "thermostat loses power"? Is this an electronic/smart thermostat and the display goes completely dead?

Comment: Does the thermostat have a battery? If so, replace it. Most thermostats except the most basic need to get power from a transformer (this is separate from using a battery to save settings), so there may be an issue with the wiring or with the actual transformer.

Comment: Yes, can you provide make/model information for the actual furnace?